# Disable button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, button, textbox

I have a Button and a TextBox in my WPF app. How can I make the Button not enabled until the user enters some text in the TextBox?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TheTextBox" />
    <Button Content="Click Me">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TheTextBox}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: It is much more elegant doing the validation in the ViewModel. Have a look at the article by Josh Smith bitbonk linked to.

Comment: @Helge Klein, I absolutely agree, but as the OP didn't specify that he was using MVVM and it isn't trivial to switch over to it if you aren't familiar, I figured I'd just answer in the simplest possible fashion.

Comment: I understand. I just wanted to point future readers to the "better" if initially more complex solution.

Comment: How Can I achieve the same for multiple textboxes and few comboxboxes but not for all of them?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee just apply the same style to all of the textboxes/comboboxes that should be affected

Comment: Man, I have to write this amount of code just to turn the button disabled? WPF sucks!

Comment: This answer is outdated by now, MVVM is much better. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906437/7204688

Answer (score 29):

In [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (wich makes a lot of things a lot easier - you should try it) you would have two properties in your ViewModel `Text` that is bound to your TextBox and you would have an `ICommand` property `Apply` (or similar) that is bound to the button:

```
<Button Command="Apply">Apply</Button>
```

The `ICommand` interface has a Method `CanExecute` that is where you return `true` `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text)`. The rest is done by WPF for you (enabling/disabling, executing the actual command on click).

The linked article explains it in detail.

Comment: This needs more upvotes and should be marked as the answer. As @jairhumberto noted, doing it in purely XAML does completely suck. MVVM has a bit of a learning curve but as this answer says, the solution to your problem, once you're using MVVM, is phenomenally simple.

Comment: I also think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 28):

By code:

```
btn_edit.IsEnabled = true;
```

By XAML:

```
<Button Content="Edit data" Grid.Column="1" Name="btn_edit" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this isn't as elegant as the other posts, but it's a more straightforward xaml/codebehind example of how to accomplish the same thing.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBox Name="TextBox01" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70" />
   <Button Name="Button01" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
Private Sub Window1_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        Button01.IsEnabled = False
        Button01.Content = "I am Disabled"

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox01_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox01.TextChanged

        If TextBox01.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
            Button01.IsEnabled = True
            Button01.Content = "I am Enabled"
        Else
            Button01.IsEnabled = False
            Button01.Content = "I am Disabled"
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It windows 8 beta it is going to be the only possibility to achieve this. At least for today.

Answer (score 2):

You could subscribe to the `TextChanged` event on the `TextBox` and if the text is empty set the `Button` to disabled. Or you could bind the `Button.IsEnabled` property to the `TextBox.Text` property and use a converter that returns true if there is any text and false otherwise.

Comment: I was gonna write "it's usefull in 2023" but I have noticed the post is in 2010! I think it's interesting that even though this is the definitive correct answer to the question, nobody cares since 2010!