# In WPF how to Make Button enabled/disabled depending on the input of different TextBox Text property?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to Make Button enabled/disabled depending on the input of different TextBox Text property using wpf binding ?

> Related question: [Make Button enabled/disabled depending on the TextBox Text property in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468160/make-button-enabled-disabled-depending-on-the-textbox-text-property-in-wpf)

I saw this question similar but this enabling/disabling depends on one TextBox.

Is there any way to bind a button enabling/disabling with more than one TextBox Text properties ? Specifically, need to disable/enable the button based on a ItemsControl containing a list of TextBox ?

Comment: You could use [MultiBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468160/make-button-enabled-disabled-depending-on-the-textbox-text-property-in-wpf

Comment: @ckruczek he do not have different textBoxes, he has a itemsControl with textBoxes, not the same thing.

Comment: Google for MVVM, this is pretty common and easy job for ViewModel. Idea is to use bindings for all such controls (nested list of controls? datatemplate and ViewModel for each, then parent ViewModel simply access the list of ViewModels to check values), then if one is changed you update your command, which makes button enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to approach this problem in an MVVM way.

Usually when working with a `Button` you set the `Command` property in XAML...

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" Content="Click Me"/>
```

and in your view model you have a [`ICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) associated with it.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ICommand _myCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myCommand== null)
            {
                _myCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    p => this.CanMyCommandExecute(),
                    p => this.MyCommandExecute()
            }
            return _myCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

You see that you create the `ICommand` instance in your view model and write the code for `CanExecute` method there too.
The `CanExecute` method returns a bool which tells whether the command is able to execute under the current conditions.

**WPF will automatically disable or enable the button connected with the `ICommand` depending on whether the CanExcute method returns `true` or `false`.**

In the "CanExecute" method you can write code which takes the values of several other bound properties of your view model into account and then returns true of false.

So let's say you have 3 `TextBox` controls and 3 bound string values in your view model.
In the CanExecute method you check the values of these 3 strings properties and return true or false.
The button will then be enabled or disabled accordingly.

Comment: It's not dynamically changing. After setting the value in the text box and need to click somewhere , then only the enable disable activates.

Comment: Triggers on a Textbox don't happen until focus changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these simple steps, I do not wanted to write the whole code by myself but feel free to ask in case you find it difficult:
1. Based on the linked question, Set the `ElementName` as the `ItemsControlName`.
2. Create a converter that takes the control as `value`. In the `convert()` , check the conditions on the Items of the `ItemsControl`(value) & return disabled/Enabled(False/true) from the `convert()`.
3.Create an instance of the `converter` with a key inside `Windows.Resources`.
4. Add the converter to the `IsEnabled="{ElementName=ItemsControlName,Path={Binding},Converter={StaticResource convKey}}"`.
You might get some syntactical errors,please correct them & give it a try.

Comment: I tried it using converter, but it is not changing the enable disable of my button while I change the text box in ItemsControl. the converter is not calling while the values change inside itemcontrol textbox.