# WPF Button Style Template IsEnabled

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

i based my application on this 
[example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views)

i need my own button-style (without mouseover animations etc.), so i made this in the app.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                        CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

my button: `<Button IsEnabled="true"/>`

now if i change the button to `<Button IsEnabled="false"/>` my app crashes at the start with an error like: "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" is not a valid value for property "BorderBrush".

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable button in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906346/disable-button-in-wpf)

Comment: @user3815356 is `DisabledBorderBrush` a valid `Brush` resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with your static reference.

In particular, XAML parsing is very touchy on order - you have to make sure that a brush with  `x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush"` is referenced *before* the parser gets to the line in the above style - even if your style above is in the same file as the `DisabledForegroundBrush`.

If you don't have a brush yet for the `DisabledForegroundBrush`, you can either remove the line referencing it in the above code if you don't require it, or, if you want it, you can create one as follows:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="Red" />
```

Where you can choose the color as appropriate. Alternatively, you can choose some other kind of brush here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904(v=vs.110).aspx

If you have a brush you'd like to use already, then if you could provide a little more information as to where the brush is in the code base (eg is it in a resource dictionary?) and where the `DisabledForegroundBrush` brush is, this might help me pinpoint an actual solution / best way of ensuring the brush is referenced.

*Note: an alternative if you can't ensure that `DisabledForegroundBrush` is parsed first is to change the `StaticResource` to a `DynamicResource`, but this isn't recommended unless the resource's link might actually change at run time (see [What's the difference between StaticResource and DynamicResource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf) )*

### An easier solution:

If you just want to hard-code the style in, instead of reference the foreground brush externally, then you could change the line:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
```

to:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="[SOME COLOR]"/>
```

To get rid of the need to create a separate brush object for your font.

Comment: this was it! thanks a lot, i thought i'm gonna get crazy today. the static resources were defined, but AFTER the style. sometimes it is just as easy as moving a few lines of code. thanks again!

Comment: Haha yep, completely agreed with you on the crazy front! Only learnt XAML myself a few months back and there were days I went absolutely mad before its idiosyncracsies began to make sense.
Glad I could help :)