# C# WIndows phone disable button after one press

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a Windows Phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2013.
I have a page where a user sees an image and button labelled "Complete".  The user has to do (in real life) what is in the image, and then press the button.  After the button is pressed he is awarded 3 points.

Once the user presses the button, the first time, I would like to disable it.  Right now, there is a bug where the user can press it many times and gain more points from one task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
 Button myButton = FindName("ButtonName") as Button;
 myButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

For more information check this: [Disable button in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906346/disable-button-in-wpf)