# How do i enable/disable a TextBox and a label based on Check Box in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

How do I enable or disable a `Label` and `textbox` based on `checkbox` input in **WPF**??

**CheckBox**

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}"  Foreground="#FFF9F3F3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32.844,-5.293,0,0" Width="216" Content="Sim Needs Passwprd?" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="18.043" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Background="#FFF4F4F4"/>
```

**TextBox and Label**

```
<Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}" Content="Sim User Name" Margin="14.439,17.192,-83.497,15"  d:IsStaticText="True" Background="#00D32626" x:Name="Label_SimUName" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Row="2" />
<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="29.844,15.885,0,16.307" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="288">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ValueTextBox_Sim}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Column="1" Text="TextBox" x:Name="TextBox_SimUName" ClipToBounds="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="286"/>
</Border>

<Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}" Content="Sim Password" Margin="14.439,-4,-83.497,0"  d:IsStaticText="True" Background="#00D32626" x:Name="Label_SimPassword" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="29.844,-5.307,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="288" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ValueTextBox_Sim}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Column="1" Text="TextBox" x:Name="TextBox_SimPassword" ClipToBounds="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="288"/>
</Border>
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Please fix your question up, its hard to read. take a tour of the help if you are unsure how to use the formatting tools

Comment: Can you please help me with the same?As this point i am new to this and i am a slow learner.

Comment: do you want to solve it via XML or c#?

Comment: @ I have already defined certain styling for the elements,It would be helpful if its via XML styling.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an event on the checkbox
2. Use this C# command :

   yourObject.IsEnabled = true/false;

more help : [Disable button in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906346/disable-button-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

Add Checked and unchecked events to your checkbox like below in XAML

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}"   Foreground="#FFF9F3F3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32.844,-5.293,0,0" 
Width="216" Content="Sim Needs Passwprd?" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="18.043" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Background="#FFF4F4F4" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
```

And in its .cs file do this.

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox_SimPassword.IsEnabled = false;
        Label_SimPassword.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox_SimPassword.IsEnabled = true;
        Label_SimPassword.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

You can enable your textbox and label based on unchecked or checked event.